# Determine if Matlab has a display available

Tags: matlab, user-interface, command-line

I would like to use `questdlg` within a Matlab application to prompt user feedback. If no display is available (e.g. over a non-forwarded ssh session or if Matlab is started with `-nodisplay`), `questdlg` fails (see below). Is there any way to determine if a display is available from within Matlab code so that I can fall back to a text-based alternative?

If Matlab is started with the `-nodisplay` option, `qusetdlg` produces the following output and "hangs" Matlab (in `uiwait`). Although the user can use `Ctl-C` to escape, there's no indication of this option and a naive user might conclude that Matlab was truly hung:

```
>> questdlg('test','test')
Warning: This functionality is no longer supported under the -nodisplay and
-noFigureWindows startup options. For more information, see "Changes to
-nodisplay and -noFigureWindows Startup Options" in the MATLAB Release Notes.
To view the release note in your system browser, run
web('http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/rn/br5ktrh-1.html#br5ktrh-3',
'-browser') 
> In uitools/private/warnfiguredialog at 19
  In dialog at 37
  In questdlg at 117
Warning: This functionality is no longer supported under the -nodisplay and
-noFigureWindows startup options. For more information, see "Changes to
-nodisplay and -noFigureWindows Startup Options" in the MATLAB Release Notes.
To view the release note in your system browser, run
web('http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/rn/br5ktrh-1.html#br5ktrh-3',
'-browser') 
> In uitools/private/warnfiguredialog at 19
  In uiwait at 41
  In questdlg at 378
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say that `questdlg` fails. Does it give an error, a warning, or does it just not work?

Comment: @gnovice It looks like it "hangs" Matlab in `uiwait`. See my edit.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

First of all, here is a list of relevant startup options, along with the operating system on which they are supported (otherwise they are ignored and have no effect):

- `-nojvm` [UNIX] : start without JVM, anything that requires Java fails (including Handle Graphics functionality)
- `-nodisplay` [UNIX]: does not use X-Window display, ignores `$DISPLAY` environment variable
- `-noFigureWindows` [ALL] : headless mode, no figure will be shown
- `-nodesktop` [ALL] : IDE not started, command prompt instead

Since I only have access to a Windows install of MATLAB, I would be thankful If someone can replicate the following experiments on UNIX, by starting MATLAB with the `-nodisplay` option, or runing without the `DISPLAY` environment variable set, in combination with the `-nodisplay` and `-nojvm` options.

#### matlab -nodesktop

```
» [usejava('jvm'),usejava('awt'),usejava('mwt'),usejava('Desktop')]
ans =
     1     1     1     0
» get(0,'ScreenSize')
ans =
           1           1        1600        1024
» feature('ShowFigureWindows')
ans =
     1
» questdlg('?','?');
[works fine]
» plot(1:10)
[works fine]
```

#### matlab -noFigureWindows

```
» [usejava('jvm'),usejava('awt'),usejava('mwt'),usejava('Desktop')]
ans =
     1     1     1     1
» get(0,'ScreenSize')
ans =
           1           1        1600        1024
» feature('ShowFigureWindows')
ans =
     0
» questdlg('?','?');
Warning: This functionality is no longer supported ....
» plot(1:10)
[no plot]
```

#### matlab -nodesktop -noFigureWindows

```
» [usejava('jvm'),usejava('awt'),usejava('mwt'),usejava('Desktop')]
ans =
     1     1     1     0
» get(0,'ScreenSize')
ans =
           1           1        1600        1024
» feature('ShowFigureWindows')
ans =
     0
» questdlg('?','?');
Warning: This functionality is no longer supported ....
» plot(1:10)
[no plot]
```

---

In conclusion, this is the test I would use to get consistent results across platforms:

```
if usejava('jvm') && ~feature('ShowFigureWindows')
    %# use text-based alternative (input)
else
    %# use GUI dialogs (questdlg)
end
```

Some references:

- [Changes to -nojvm Startup Option](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html#brubkzc-1)
- [Changes to -nodisplay and -noFigureWindows Startup Options](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html#br5ktrh-3)
- [usejava](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/usejava.html), [javachk](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/javachk.html)
- [matlabwindows](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlabwindows.html), [matlabunix](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlabunix.html)
- `which -all warnfiguredialog.m`

Comment: I can confirm. On linux usejava('Desktop') == 0 if you use Matlab from the terminal w/o a X-server.

Comment: `feature('ShowFigureWindows')` is true for me on `2016b` even with `-noFigureWindows`

Comment: @Eric are you sure? I just tried it myself on R2016b (Windows 10), and `feature('ShowFigureWindows')` returns false in `-noFigureWindows` headless mode.

Comment: @Amro: I'm using a multihop X11 connection, so perhaps there's a bug somewhere there. I recall it working earlier too, but seems not to now. At any rate, `-nodisplay` still works correctly

Answer (score 2):

[This MATLAB newsgroup thread](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/136261) suggests that checking the third and fourth values of the [root object `'ScreenSize'` property](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/rootobject_props.html#ScreenSize) will tell you if a display is available. I can't test it at the moment, but you could try adding this to your code:

```
screenSize = get(0,'ScreenSize');
if isequal(screenSize(3:4),[1 1])
  %# Use text-based alternative
else
  %# Call questdlg
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will work, but you could try the [`usejava`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/usejava.html) function with the 'desktop' parameter.

Comment: I think `usejava('awt')` may be better, as Matlab can be run without the desktop, but with a display available.

Comment: Well, it's not a complete solution; `matlab -nojvm` says AWT is unavailable (obviously), even though a display may be available. In this case, `questdlg` appears to fallback to Motif if possible.

Answer (score 1):

`is_gui_mode = usejava('desktop') && usejava('awt');`

Comment: usejava('desktop') checks whether an IDE is running and usejava('awt') checks whether it supports "Abstract Window Toolkit" (that is used to render UI elements). If both are true, then it is a GUI-mode; if not, it is a text mode.

Comment: @victor improve your answer by editing it, not by adding comments.

Comment: @victor: as I've shown in my answer, this doesn't detect the case when MATLAB is started with the `-noFigureWindows` option (in which case `questdlg` doesn't show anything and simply hangs until you break with `Ctrl-C`). You must use the undocumented `feature('ShowFigureWindows')` to query the status of that option..

Answer (score 1):

@Amro's [answer on this page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6776191/1676217) is fine but does **not** work within `parfor` loops. In fact, none of the `usejava()` and `feature('ShowFigureWindows')` based solutions work in that case because the environment changes once a `parfor` loop starts.

A reliable way is [@gnovice's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6771356/1676217). Specifically:

```
parfor k=1:N
    scr = get(0,'ScreenSize');
    if isequal(scr(3:4),[1 1])
        % text-based version
    else
        % GUI version
    end
end
```

Alternatively, you could apply either solution **before** entering the `parfor` loop, store the result in a variable, and then check only that variable within the parfor loop:

```
scr = get(0,'ScreenSize');
istext = isequal(scr(3:4),[1 1]);

% or

istext = ~usejava('jvm') || ~feature('ShowFigureWindows');

parfor k=1:N
   if istext
       % text-based version
   else
       % GUI version
   end
end
```

However, depending on your application, this may not be reliable (e.g. if the parfor loop changes context, but that's uncommon).