# Starting Matlab textually

Tags: user-interface, command-line, terminal, matlab

In Linux terminal, I was wondering what differences are between the following four options for Matlab command?

```
matlab -nojvm -nodesktop -nodisplay -nosplash
```

1. I searched on the internet, and the four options seem to be
   redundant, especially used together?
2. Can they be ordered from more graphical to less graphical, or less
   textural to more textural? For example, can they be ordered in some
   way from weak to strong as: -nodesktop < -nojvm <-nodisplay?
3. How do you know the JVM is started in -nodisplay, and not in -nojvm?
   In other words, what functionality that is provided by JVM still
   work under -nodisplay?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: you might find this discussion relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6776191

Answer (score 6):

This is all explained in the MATLAB documentation here: http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/matlabunix.html.

-nodisplay: Start the Sun Microsystems JVM software, but do not start the MATLAB desktop. Do not display any X commands, and ignore the DISPLAY environment variable,

-nodesktop: Start MATLAB without bringing up the MATLAB desktop. The JVM software is started. Use the current window in the operating system to enter commands. Use this option to run without an X-window, for example, in VT100 mode, or in batch processing mode. Note that if you pipe to MATLAB using the > constructor, the nodesktop option is used automatically. With nodesktop, MATLAB does not save statements to the Command History. With nodesktop, you can still use most development environment tools by starting them via a function. For example, use preferences to open the Preferences dialog box and doc to open the Help browser. Do not use nodesktop to provide a Command Window-only interface; instead, select Desktop > Desktop Layout > Command Window Only.

-nojvm: Start MATLAB without the JVM software. Use the current window to enter commands. The MATLAB desktop does not open. Any tools that require Java software, such as the desktop tools, cannot be used. Handle Graphics and related functionality are not supported; MATLAB produces a warning when you use them.

-nosplash: starts MATLAB but does not display the splash screen during startup.

Comment: Thanks! Although I think I have read that, (1) I still wonder if there are some redundancy in the four options, especially used together? (2) Can they be ordered from more graphical to less graphical, or less textural to more textural?

Comment: (3) How do you know the JVM is started in -nodisplay, and not in -nojvm? In other words, what functionality that is provided by JVM still work under -nodisplay? (4) Can they be ordered in some way as: -nodesktop < -nojvm <-nodisplay?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you can still plot graphs with -nodesktop, which you can't with -nojvm. Should be easy to test ;). I think the ordering is rather: -nodesktop > -nodisplay > -nojvm, ordering from "can do most" to "can do least".

Comment: Thanks! (1) in -nojvm, I can still plot, while in -nodisplay, I cannot plot. (2) In -nodisplay, it says JVM is still loaded, I wonder how to know the JVM is started in -nodisplay, and not in -nojvm? In other words, what functionality that is provided by JVM still work under -nodisplay?

Comment: Hm, I'm afraid I can't help you there.