# matlab -nodesktop command history: cannot be saved

Tags: matlab, command-line, history

1 I run matlab without GUI, sometimes I would like to see commandhisoty by using commandhistory function, but I found that if I run matlab without GUI, the program cannot save any command history like the GUI matlab, are there some methods to solve this problem?

2 I tyied to use diary, but it seems that it can only save **all** commands and outputs. In addition, it seems that I should type diary every time when I open matlab, the default option is diary off. How to make it more convenient to use

Comment: Sorry, but something does not make sense to me: how would you want the command window history, if your command window is not active? (because you don't launch the MATLAB IDE) How do you issue your commands?

Comment: 1) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9703317/starting-matlab-textually This explains why you can't. 2) Add `diary on` to startup script.